# Open a window and write to that window

Tags: javascript

I work on a Firebug extension which is Firefox extension. From my extension I have to create a report. I am trying to open a new window and write code into it. I am able to open a window with the below code but not able to write anything to that window. I get an error "`newWindow.document.write()` is not secure"

If I use `document.body.innerHTML()` I am able to write the content to the window but I want to do it in other way as the text generated from my tool has the script and css in it.

Here is my code snippet:

```
var newWindow = window.open ("","Test","width=335,height=330,resizable=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,status=0")


newWindow .document.open()
// html is the data to be shown on the window. It has script and 
// the content in it.
newWindow .document.write(html)
newWindow .document.close()
```

Comment: Well, you have extra spaces for one thing. For example `newWindow .document` should be `newWindow.document`.

Comment: Your answer lies here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569374/how-to-set-the-innerhtml-of-some-element-in-a-window-opened-by-a-javascript-wind

Comment: oh it is a typo while posting it in here. My original code doesnot have them...

Comment: Which browser throws that error?

Answer (score 3):

use like this:

```
<script>
var w = window.open('', 'wnd');

w.document.body.innerHTML = "<b>Hello, stackoverflow!</b>";
</script>
```

Comment: "If I use `document.body.innerHTML()` I am able to write the content to the window but I want to do it in other way as the text generated from my tool has the script and css in it."